# AngularJS : How to get the uncompiled transclude content of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to use the transclude content of a directive (the original content of the directive, not the template), as the HTML template of a row in a grid.

```
<grid attrs="...">
    <action-column-template>...(html I need)...</action-column-template>
</grid>
```

The idea is that I need the action-column-template's raw HTML (uncompiled, unbinded to any scope).

I do not control the generation of each row, so I can't manually bind that action template to each row's scope using transclude(rowScope). I just need it as plain html (i.e. with "{{ }}"s and inner directives untouched).

Running the transclude() fn from the link function gives me the transcluded content, but binded to a scope and with inner directives expanded. And the html() of the tElem param of the compile function returns the HTML of the directive's template, not the content to be transcluded.

So the question is: can I get the content-to-be-transcluded of a directive in its compile, controller, preLink or postLink functions as uncompiled HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `tElem.contents()` from within compile?

Comment: of course. It returns the contents of the directive's template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `terminal: true`, and manually compile the directive.

Comment: Set `terminal: true` for which directive? And manually compile which directive?